# Nuxt meta-tags not scraped by Facebook Debugger

Tags: vue.js, metadata, nuxt.js, meta-tags, meta

I'm using Nuxt (Universal), connected to Wordpress with Apollo and Graphql.

I'm fetching my content with:

```
  async asyncData({ app, params, store, route, redirect }) {

    await store.dispatch("actionSetPageContents", {
      axios: app.$axios,
      apollo: app.apolloProvider.defaultClient,
      route: route,
      redirect: redirect
    });

    return {
      pageContents: store.getters["getPageContent"]
    };
```

Already tested without async and await but with no luck.

I'm defining my meta-tags this way:

```
 head() {
    return {
      title: this.pageContents.seo.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: this.pageContents.seo.metaDesc
        },
        // Open Graph
        {
          hid: "og:title",
          property: "og:title",
          content: this.pageContents.seo.title,
          vmid: "og:title"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

I have the other OG required meta-tags but omitted them in this post.

I can see my meta-tags defined in the page source as follows:

```
<meta data-n-head="ssr" data-hid="og:title" property="og:title" content="Página Inicial" vmid="og:title">
```

This code works on Skype, Slack, etc. But for some reason, Facebook doesn't seem to pick up the meta. **(The following required properties are missing: og:title, ...)**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook seems to skip `meta` tags with extra (non-standard) attributes (i.e. `data-n-head="ssr"`)

You can tidy your pre-rendered markup using [generator hooks](https://nuxtjs.org/api/internals-generator#hooks) in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
...
  hooks: {
    'generate:page': page => {
      page.html = page.html.replace(/ data-n-head=".*?"/gi, '').replace(/ data-hid=".*?"/gi, '')
    },
  },
...
```

You should also delete `vmid: "og:title"` from meta declaration in `head()` (please refer to the example on [this page](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head/))

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue now. Nuxt 2.14.3 builds successfully scraped by Facebook.

Comment: Google was skipping canonical tags. This worked for me. Using nuxt 2.15.7 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags will be work only for Server side rendering - SSR nuxt project. If you r *nuxt.config.js* file **target value static** then it will be **server**.

I have tried lots with different types of meta tags. When i understand it have to be server side rendering then tried this way. After all this i got success.

I have tried another way with Client side rendering. You can change with nginx configuration for crawler. When request come from crawler then you can send it to you PHP folder.